# Decrease separation between columns beamer

Tags: beamer, alignment, columns

I want to align an image with some text in a beamer frame. From what I've read on other questions, one way to do this is to use the command \begin{columns}. However, something is not formatted as I need it at the very end. This is my code and the frame created.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivación}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htp]
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{frobenius.jpg}
            \caption{Ferdinand Georg Frobenius}
        \end{figure}
        \end{column}      
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \justifying
            Ferdinand Georg Frobenius (26 October 1849 – 3 August 1917) was a German mathematician, best known for his contributions to the theory of elliptic functions, differential equations, number theory, and to group theory. 
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

The right margin is very small and the text is very close to the end of the frame. I don't like this. I would like to either move the text a bit to the left or to make the margin bigger, but only in this frame. Can someone help me?

**Edit** I am using the Madrid theme and `\usepackage{ragged2e}` to justify text.

Comment: Why don't you just resize the width of the right column down from 48%? Or adjust both values, so that they are not equal in width.

Comment: It seems your problems are related to things not included in the MWE, such as the the theme and whatever package \justifying comes from.

Comment: @Ingmar that doesn't work: if I do that, the columns get smaller and more sepparated from each other, but they maintain the same distance from the margins.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I added that in my  edit.

Comment: Madrid provides very narrow margins compared to other themes.  If you are not required to use it, don't.  If you ARE required to use it, learn to live with small margins.

Comment: BTW, you might find `\rule{1pt}{\ht\strutbox}\hfill\rule{1pt}{\ht\strutbox}\par` useful to see where the margins are.

Answer (score 1):

Your prescribed image width (4cm) is smaller then prescribed column width (0.58\textwidth ~ 48mm), consequently appears that column separation is large.

Distance between image and text you can reduce by defined width of image as `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}`. If resulted size of image is to big, you can reduce first column width to approximately to `0.44\linewidth` (~ 4.2cm) and adequate increase width of the second column (to about `0.56\linewidth`.

With this settings you will get:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivación}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.42\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htp]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{frobenius.jpg}
            \caption{Ferdinand Georg Frobenius}
        \end{figure}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.56\textwidth}
            %\justifying
            Ferdinand Georg Frobenius (26 October 1849 – 3 August 1917) was a German mathematician, best known for his contributions to the theory of elliptic functions, differential equations, number theory, and to group theory.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: please always provide MWE, a complete small document which we can compile as it is. By this you help us to help you.